# Como resolver este erro retornando de acesso ao web service?

Tags: json, ios, web-service, objective-c, afnetworking

Estou desenvolvendo um app que consome dados de um web service e usando o **AFNetworking** para fazer as requisições.

Durante a fase de testes o app funcionou e recebeu os dados normalmente.
Então exportei o banco de dados para o web service online e tive o seguinte problema:

> -[_NSInlineData count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x161f0e00
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSInlineData count]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x161f0e00'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x22f10f87 0x3066fc77 0x22f1637d 0x22f14259 0x22e45d68 0x4329d 0x1c7b1 0x1b7ad3 0x1b7abf 0x1bb51b
>   0x22ed6e61 0x22ed5581 0x22e22db1 0x22e22bc3 0x2a1ad051 0x263edf01
>   0x3b0e5 0x30c0baaf) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

Comment: Esta exceção significa que você está chamando algum método que não existe no objeto. Talvez pelos dados virem diferente ou não como você espera e não há algum tratamento para isso. Use *breakpoints* para chegar até a linha do erro e facilitar a localização exata deste erro.

Comment: Sim eu encontrei o erro, era pq eu estava codificando o recebimento, e na verdade nao era necessario! So achei isso uma instabilidade do AFNetworking, que funcionou de um jeito com o BD local, e teve outro comportamento com um banco de dados clonado, e hospedado na web.

Comment: apenas uma dica @TiagoAmaral, adiciona a tua solução encontrada numa nova resposta e adiciona como a correta para o teu problema. irá ajudar os outros a entender melhor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim eu encontrei o erro, era pq eu estava codificando o recebimento, e na verdade nao era necessario! So achei isso uma instabilidade do AFNetworking, que funcionou de um jeito com o BD local, e teve outro comportamento com um banco de dados clonado, e hospedado na web.